# jQuery scroll doesn't work on iPad/iOS properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have a small script that detects the scrollTop position of the window, and if the user has scrolled 43px, the banner shrinks and fixes to the top of the screen.

```
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( top > 43 ) {
            small_banner();
        } else if ( top <= 43 ) { 
            large_banner();
        }
    });
```

This works perfectly on a desktop computer or even an android device, but it becomes buggy on my iPad. Sometimes the banner won't appear when the user scrolls pass 43px, and sometimes it will appear for a second and disappear.

How would I fix this? Thank you!